# Constraints not works correctly in a Present ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, layout, constraints

I've a ViewController like PopUp but the View not stay in position that I wants.

I want that this View stay on the center of screen. The below screen show the View in storyboard with the constraints seted and the result on simulator.

[image]

AlertViewController.swift

```
class AlertViewController : UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var frameView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var btCancel: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblInfo: UILabel!

    var delegate : AlertViewControllerDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        
        self.frameView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    }

    @IBAction func cancel(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.cancelBt()
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

MainViewController.swift (show)

```
let alertController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AlertVC") as! AlertViewController
            alertController.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true
            alertController.definesPresentationContext = true
            alertController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.crossDissolve
            alertController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
            alertController.delegate = self

            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: {})
```

**EDIT**

I tried this.

[image]

The result: (I did change the background color).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is setting top , bottom , leading and trailing constraints with  static values that may break when you run in device , you need to set

> width,height,centerX,centerY

*** good practise to make width & height proportional to screen with multiplier or content size dependent ***

top label

> top , centerX

activity

> top to label , centerX

mid label

> centerX,Y

cancel button

> centerX , bottom

Comment: you duplicate centerX in the screenShoot , you need centerX and Y

Comment: Yes.. Frame View.centerY and View.centerX.

Comment: i see red warning may be you have an issue in it , do you position all elemnts correctly inside the frameView ??

Comment: Yes, I tried many ways, reset to suggest, set one by one... The `UIViews` inside can influence on the main frame? about constraints, of course.

Comment: Do you set  centerX constraint for every subview inside frameView , if no set it

Comment: I did exactly that you wrote. But not works. I edited the question with the result.

Comment: @Augusto Can you share a demo of this vc only in github ?

Comment: I can do this without create a new project?

Comment: create a new project and copy that vc from Edit->copy

Comment: I did this and the layout works fine! But in my real project the bug occurs! On the new project (just copy and paste vc): https://imgur.com/a/DEgiv7v

Comment: What could be causing this only in my original project?Why

Answer (score 0):

Your issue doesn't seem to be with the constraints of the content for your alert, but with the placement/constraints of the view that you're presenting in respect with your Parent View. It would seem that you'd need to set your alert-viewer's height-width values and x,y coordinates manually in code to make them present correctly.

[EDIT]
I just noticed the order that your constraints are set. Make sure you're dragging from your FrameView to your SuperView and setting the constraint in that direction. That is, FIRST ITEM: FrameView.... SECOND ITEM: SuperView... That might also be a reason for your troubles.

There's also a good discussion on some issues with auto-layout and PresentViewController here: [Auto layout invalid after presenting view controller (and many situation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666907/auto-layout-invalid-after-presenting-view-controller-and-many-situation)

Either way, I would recommend using Center Horizontally and Center Vertically as opposed to fixed-static constraint values for your 'inner view' in your AlertView. This seems to work better when scaling accross different sized displays.

**Some resources you might find useful:**

But, seeing as what you're presenting is a rather simple alertview, I'd recommend skipping the re-invention of the wheel and making use of some ready-made libraries that will make your life alot easier.

1.[EZAlertController](https://github.com/thellimist/EZAlertController) if all you need are text and action buttons.

2.[MRProgress](https://github.com/mrackwitz/MRProgress) if all you need are loading/progress indicators.

3.[NYAlertView](https://github.com/nealyoung/NYAlertViewController) if what you are looking for is the freedom to add your own UIView inside the alert.

These libraries take care of the 'pesky' constraint issues for you and make development a lot quicker.

[EDIT]
You might want to take a look at: https://github.com/vsouza/awesome-ios#alert--action-sheet which has an excellent curated list of useful pods that really help with iOS development.